# Understand nosql database design

Tags: database, nosql

I am interested in how nosql databases are designed. To be specific things that I really like are support of range query, auto backup, partitioning(support of horizontal scaling) etc. Is there any book or online document to read if one is interested in building a nosql database. I know it is quite important to decide that what use-cases your database has to support. But at initial stage what are the basic structures one has to be aware of.